# Difference between a Document Library and a Document Workspace

Tags: document-library

I've created a new document library, uploaded a document, then created a folder. Now I'd like to move that document into the new folder, but I only seem to see an option for send to, which has 'Other Location' and 'Create Document Workspace' as options.

What's the difference between a document library and a document workspace?

What's the alternative method to move a document into a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't offer the possibility to move documents out of the box.

You will either

... have to download a copy of the document, upload it to the new location and delete the old version.

... have to use the Explorer View of the document library (in the "Library" tab) and move the documents like you would with any other files on your computer.

Comment: Does that not seem somewhat odd that you can't simply move a document around in various folders? 
Otherwise how else does one achieve structure amongst potentially hundreds if not thousands of files?

Comment: You're right. That's what third-party solutions to manage SharePoint structure are for - or you could use the other views like Explorer View.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Send To / Other Location to create a copy in your folder and then delete the original.

A [document workspace](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-and-manage-a-document-workspace-site-HA010158257.aspx) is a kind of site for coordinating collaboration on one or more related documents - to keep everything relating to the document(s) together, e.g. tasks, timelines, discussions, etc. Think something like marketing whitepapers and slide decks for a particular product, or a new HR policy under development, etc.

Comment: Thanks lgaud, I'm going to give the send to a try. and thanks for the answer.